# How to mock module attributes and other modules in Elixir?

Tags: testing, mocking, elixir

I'm very new to elixir so this is probably basic but couldn't see much online

if I have the following code

```
defmodule A do
  def my_first_function do
    # does stuff
  end
end

defmodule B do
    @my_module_attribute A.my_first_function()
end
```

then how do I mock module `A` in my tests so I can just tell the tests what I want it to return?

also is it possible to just mock `@my_module_attribute` instead? would be good to have an answer to both approaches (and then what is considered the better pattern)

Comment: [Mocks and explicit contracts](https://dashbit.co/blog/mocks-and-explicit-contracts)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip thanks for the link. would you be able to provide an example to help me here? I'm still seeing issues in tests where things aren't mocking correctly.

in Javascript I could just do `myFunction.mockImplementation()` or something

Comment: I'm pretty sure module attributes are fixed at compile time, so it wouldn't be possible to give an attribute a different value in different tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps you are wanting to use module attributes for more than what they are useful for, and perhaps there is some confusion over the exact definition of "mock".

Avoid thinking of module attributes as "class variables" -- even though they look like they might serve the same purpose and they are in the same place, their behavior is different.  Be especially careful when a module attribute relies on a function call.  One common pitfall is to use module attributes to store values read from configuration, e.g. using [`Application.fetch_env!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#fetch_env!/2).  The problem is that the module attributes are evaluated at *compile time* (not at run time), so you can easily end up with an unexpected value.  (The compiler now warns about this gotcha explicitly and there is now the `Application.compile_env!/2` provided to better communicate that particular use case).

I usually reserve module attributes for raising the visibility of simple constants and I tend to avoid using them for storing the result of any function execution.

When it comes back down to "mocking", you still have to think about the fact that Elixir is compiled -- it's not Javascript.  Someone geekier than me can explain the mechanics, but the module attributes don't exist the same way at runtime as they do at compile time.

"Mocking" during tests usually means substituting one module or function for another, and this swap is often easier to do at runtime.  One common pattern looks a bit like Dependency Injection (but purists may object to the comparison).

Consider a function like this that relies on some `OtherModule` to do its work:

```
def my_function(input, opts \\ []) do
  other_module = Keyword.get(opts, :service, OtherModule)
  other_module.get_thing(input)
  # do more stuff...
end
```

Instead of hard-coding the `OtherModule` inside of `my_function`, its name is read out of the optional `opts`.  This provides a useful way to override the output of that `OtherModule` when you need to test it.

In your test, you can do something like this:

```
test "example mock" do
      assert something = MyApp.MyMod.my_function("foo", service: MockService)
end
```

When the test provides `MockService` as the `:service` module, the `get_thing` function will be called on the `MockService` module and not on the `OtherModule`.  If the provided module does not define a `get_thing` function, the code will fail to execute.  This is where having a behaviour comes in handy because it helps guarantee that your module has implemented the needed functions.  The `Mox` testing library, for example, relies on the behaviour contracts, but from the example above you can see premise.

If you squint, you can see that this "injection" approach is somewhat similar to how Javascript often accepts a callback function as an argument, but in Elixir it is more common to pass around module names instead of captured functions.

Comment: thank you for that excellent explanation Everett. Off the back of that I'm wondering what is the best way to use "global variables" in Elixir? I'm creating a guessing game and I need the original word to be fixed from the start. is the elixir pattern to pass it around to every function via args? that seems not ideal (but again I'm very new to the language)

Comment: You may have heard in some languages that "everything is an object." In Elixir, you might say "everything is a function".  There are no global variables, but functions are well namespaced and unique (i.e. "global"). You can imagine something like `MyConsts.pi()` acting more or less like a constant in other languages (drop the optional parens if you'd like).

Yes: the functional pattern would be to pass the relevant values into the functions. E.g. something like `guess_number(solution, history_of_guesses)` might outline all the "state" required to run a number guessing game.